# how can I convert my work into material angular/ mat-select

Tags: angular-material

```
I'm new in angular material. How can I convert all of this into material angular? I also import material angular to my modules, I tried to use mat-select, I change select into mat-select but it didn't work. can someone help me about this?



    <input class="input-field" name="postal" type="text" placeholder="Postal Code" name="postal" required>  
<select class="input-field" name="region" id="region" onclick="makeDisable()" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdownProvince(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option disabled selected>Region</option> 
    <option value="metromanila">Metro Manila</option>
    <option value="mindanao">Mindanao</option>
    <option value="northluzon">North Luzon</option>
    <option value="southluzon">South Luzon</option>
    <option value="visayas">Visayas</option> 
</select>
```

document.write('Province')
    document.write('City')
    document.write('Barangay')

function dynamicdropdownProvince(listindex)
{
    switch (listindex)
    {
    case "metromanila" :
        document.getElementById('provincestatus').options[0]=new Option("Province","");
        document.getElementById("provincestatus").options[1]=new Option("Metro Manila","metromanila");
        document.getElementById("provincestatus").disabled=false;
        break;
    case "mindanao" :
        document.getElementById("provincestatus").options[0]=new Option("Province","");
        document.getElementById("provincestatus").options[1]=new Option("Agusan Del Norte","agusandelnorte");
        document.getElementById("provincestatus").disabled=false;
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
function dynamicdropdownCity(listindex)
{
    switch (listindex)
    {
      case "agusandelnorte" :
        document.getElementById("citystatus").options[0]=new Option("City","");
        document.getElementById("citystatus").options[1]=new Option("Buenavista","buenavista");
        document.getElementById("citystatus").disabled=false;
        break;
      case "metromanila" :
        document.getElementById("citystatus").options[0]=new Option("City","");
        document.getElementById("citystatus").options[1]=new Option("Binondo","binondo");
        document.getElementById("citystatus").disabled=false;
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
function dynamicdropdownBarangay(listindex)
{
    switch (listindex)
    {
    case "buenavista" :
      document.getElementById("barangaystatus").options[0]=new Option("Barangay","barangaystatus");
      document.getElementById("barangaystatus").options[1]=new Option("Alubijid","alubijid");
      document.getElementById("barangaystatus").disabled=false;
      break;
    case "binondo" :
      document.getElementById("barangaystatus").options[0]=new Option("Barangay","barangaystatus");
      document.getElementById("barangaystatus").options[1]=new Option("Barangay 287","barangay287");
      document.getElementById("barangaystatus").disabled=false;
      break;
    }

```
return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the steps of https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview it should work

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selectedValue">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="metromanila">Metro Manila</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="mindanao">Mindanao</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="northluzon">North Luzon</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="southluzon">South Luzon</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="visayas">Visayas</mat-option> 
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-value-binding-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-value-binding-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-value-binding-example.css'],
})
export class SelectValueBindingExample {
  selectedValue: string; <-- *will be null if nothing selected or will hold a string*
}
```

Module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, MatSelectModule
  ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```